# Topics not in preferred replica for broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

```
kafka        | [2024-02-15 13:11:15,297] INFO [Controller id=1001] Processing automatic preferred replica leader election (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka        | [2024-02-15 13:11:15,297] TRACE [Controller id=1001] Checking need to trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka        | [2024-02-15 13:11:15,298] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 1001 Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka        | [2024-02-15 13:11:15,298] TRACE [Controller id=1001] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 1001 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

i am trying to run kafka in the docker container. initially it is running fine and communicating, but in between i am getting this msg in the logs.

anyone can you helpme out from this isssue?

Answer (score 0):

There's no error here, or anything to fix. The Map() that would show you the topic names is empty, and the leader imbalance is 0.0 (so, not imbalanced).

You could turn off TRACE level logging to hide those lines

If there were topic replicas out of sync or offline, there are other ways to monitor that, such as JMX metrics

Comment: as i was running publisher and multiple subscribers then after some time i am getting and  due to this communication is not happening .

Comment: could please explain in detail to solve this as i am running in docker